How to use AddIdentityApiEndpoints inside a class library?
I have separated my identity code into a dedicated class library. I have an IServiceCollection extension method for adding everything I need except this one line:
builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

No matter which package I include, AddIdentityApiEndpoints is never recognized. What do I need to do to be able to use AddIdentityApiEndpoints from within a class library?

That's what I was missing. The framework reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref. It's not obvious from the documentation page that that is a framework reference as opposed to a package reference.

The documentation page's "Definition" section is terse, but it essentially says that you need to have:

a <FrameworkReference> to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref in your .csproj.
a <PackageReference> to Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core in your .csproj.
a using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection namespace import in your Startup.cs


Yeah, my confusion comes from the fact that both Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref and Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core are listed in the "Packages" list, so I thought they're both package references.
